# Ruby on rails - undefined method in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined

I am trying to display the name of the faculty instead of just the ID.

Everything else works except that part where I try to display the name of the faculty. I get an error saying "undefined method" .

I know I am doing something wrong, but I cannot figure it out at all even though I have been looking at this for hours. I am a completely beginner and I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<!-- notice is a ruby method, and its results comes here inside the tags
used when you want the errow page to show on the next page -->
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @student.name %> 
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Faculty:</strong>
  <%= @student.faculty_id %>
  <%= @name.faculty_id %> 


</p>

 <strong>Grade:</strong>
  <%= @student.grade%>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(@student) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', students_path %>
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :faculty

end
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :faculty
end
```

faculty.rb

```
class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student
    # belongs_to :faculty
    has_many :name
end
```

This is my students_controler.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /students
  # GET /students.json
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /students/new
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  # GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /students/1
  # PATCH/PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update(student_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /students/1
  # DELETE /students/1.json
  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to students_url, notice: 'Student was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:name, :faculty_id)
    end
end
```

The error is undefined method `faculty_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Posting the actual error would be a great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to display the name of the faculty instead of just the ID

Since you're a beginner, let me explain it for you...

--

You're currently calling `@student.faculty_id`

This is the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of the `@student` object -- the identifier which links this `student` object to the appropriate `faculty` object.

In short, it means that this attribute is a part of the `student` schema -- you want one which is part of the `faculty` schema. Thus, you either need to use [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) to call the `name` attribute from `faculty`, or just call it directly:

```
@student.faculty.name
```

---

There are deeper problems with your *model associations*.
[image]

[The above](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) is how they should be set up:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :faculty
end

#app/models/faculty.rb
class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students
end
```

The above will allow you to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @student = Student.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/students/view.html.erb
<%= @student.faculty.name %>
```

You must remember that Rails works on top of a [*relational database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). This works by allowing you to call related objects by virtue of their *foreign key*.

I can explain more if required.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @name.faculty_id %>` won't work.

In your controller eager load the faculty

```
def show
  @student = Student.includes(:faculty)
end
```

Either do

```
<% if @student.faculty.present? %>
  <%= @student.faculty.name %>
<% end %>
```

or you could get the faculty in the controller and assign it to a variable

```
def show
  @student = Student.includes(:faculty)
  @faculty = @student.faculty
end
```

Then you can use that

```
<% if @faculty.present? %>
  <%= @faculty.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I don't understand where the codes you wrote are meant to be put.. Could you help me on that?

Comment: Well the bits defined as show should be in the controller, and the other bit in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Error which I see is

```
class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :student
# belongs_to :faculty
has_many :name
end
```

Should be

```
class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :students
# belongs_to :faculty
has_many :names
end
```

I don't know your error due to this is or not but has_many is not with singular form